# PS - Iterate over string array to detect orphaned user directories

Tags: windows, powershell, user-profile

We have an issue whereby standard windows profile removal methods via intune are not working correctly, often leaving orphaned user directories in C\Users, which saturates the C: drive.

I'm trying to make a PS script to:

- Get user profiles (normal users)
- Get (normal) user directories in C:\Users
- Determine which directories do not correspond to a user profile
- Delete those directories

(I'm a PS novice.. )

```
# Get user directories
[string[]]$Directories = Get-ChildItem C:\users | 
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_ -notlike "*Windows*" -and $_ -notlike "*default*" -and $_ -notlike "*Public*" -and $_ -notlike "*Admin*"} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Name}    

# Get user profiles
[string[]]$Profiles = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special = 'False'" | Select-Object LocalPath | Out-String

#Iterate
Foreach($Directory in $Directories) {
    
    if(("C:\users\" + $Directory) -notin $Profiles){
        ## complete some task
    }

}
```

I can see that I'm missing something basic r.e. the iteration. If I comment out the `if` loop add `write-host $Directory` it will list the directories, but only the first has C:\Users\ prepended.

I'm also assuming I've constructed the arrays incorrectly, althoguh they appear to be arrays of strings?

If working correctly, creating an empty folder 'Test' in C:\Users\ and adding `write-host $Directory` inside the `if` loop should result in only 'Test' being output.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell as a language, unlike a lot of languages, is a dynamically typed language. Meaning, there's no need to *typecast* (*in most situations*) anything for a returning output.

That said, you also don't have to *stringify* any of its output (*via `Out-String`*) when you can work with the properties directly:

```
$users_folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users' -Exclude 'Admin', 'Public' -Directory).FullName
$profile_paths = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_UserProfile' -Filter "Special = 'False'").LocalPath
foreach ($folder in $users_folders)
{
    if ($folder -notin $profile_paths)
    {
        $folder
    }
}
```

You'll have to take note of the *grouping* operator `(...)`, when applied to collections, it allows direct access to properties of the items inside. If you have an array of objects and you use the grouping operator followed by a property name, such as `LocalPath` or `FullName`, PowerShell will return the value of that property for each object in the collection. This is also known as [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3).